# Extremely slow git clone on windows

Tags: windows-10, git, clone

I am cloning a repository that is on BitBucket server, but my cloning speed is extremely slow. See the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried cloning with TortoiseGit, GitBash, SourceTree but all of them have the same issue. 
I saw many related question to this but none of them helped.

Comment: It could be an issue on BitBucket's side, such as server down for maintenance, or an issue on the CDN's side.  For example, some of the servers could be down for maintenance, so traffic may be being throttled to ensure users can still access data.  If this is the case, it should resolve within 8 - 24hrs, depending on the maintenance being performed.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Git clone in windows much slower than in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768893/git-clone-in-windows-much-slower-than-in-linux)
says to verify your network interface parameters.
The interface with the Git server might use inefficient settings.

The accepted solution was to run in an elevated Command Prompt the following commands:

```
netsh interface tcp show global
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal

netsh interface tcp show heuristics
netsh interface tcp set heuristics disabled
```

The first command in each pair will display the setting's value.
Use the second command if it is different from the indicated setting.